# ASP.NET Core 2.1 External login Fails in Production

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I have a project at work were I need to use Google and Microsoft Account for login. So far it works as it should on local host, however `SignInManager<IdentityUser>.ExternalLoginSignInAsync` fails for both in the same way when deployed on the server. The user gets through the external login dialog as if it worked but fails in the callback.

The `SignInResult` offers no explanation other than "Failed". Note that this is first time I'm using ASP.Net Core, so I wouldn't be surprised if I missed something vital. The site doesn't use the autogenerated login pages.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardClientCertificate = false;
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
        });

        services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(SqlConfigurationDatabase.Credentials));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(name: "add", template: "{controller=Product}/{action=Add}");
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to include the rest of login code. As for the markup:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" target="_blank" class="form-horizontal">
@{
    foreach (var provider in await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync())
    {
        var name = provider.DisplayName + ".png";
        <button type="submit" name="provider" value="@provider.DisplayName" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">
            <img src="~/images/@name" />
            @provider.DisplayName
        </button>
    }
}
</form>
```

The Home controller is the only one that talks with the external login services.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> users;

    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> signIn;

    public HomeController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        users = userManager;
        signIn = signInManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        if (signIn.IsSignedIn(User))
            return RedirectToLocal("/Product/Abc123");

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Gdpr()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Home", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        var properties = signIn.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);

        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }

        var info = await signIn.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

        var result = await signIn.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        else
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    private IActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        else
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await signIn.SignOutAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

There is no load-balancing, clustering, web farms or any other fancy stuff going on at this time. I have basically just tweaked the example site created by Visual Studio (ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Application with authentication set to *Individual User Accounts*).

Comment: Are you employing any load-balancing, clustering, web farms, etc.?

Comment: If you're not using the autogenerated pages for login, what *are* you using? It's really just guesswork at this stage without knowing what you're code is doing. For example, you'll get a `Failed` result if you're trying to sign in the user without an account existing within your Identity database itself.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Interesting, but wouldn't that also be the case when debugging on localhost?

Comment: Well that depends on the database - it's plausible that you might've created an account previously that now lives in said database on localhost.

Comment: @KirkLarkin You might be onto something here. I just nuked the database on the localhost. Now the local hosted version has the same problem. So to confirm this is the problem I need to create an account before the using the third party login right? But for that to happen I need to know the email of the user. If I remember correctly, the built in system lets the user use the third party login before being asked to create an account. The key here is that the email field is already filled. How does it do that?

Comment: Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.1/src/UI/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs#L80).

Comment: @KirkLarkin Score, that is easy to do! Unfortunately management is getting impatient... seems I have to go with scaffolding Identity. So I can't test out your idea at the moment. But you seem to have hit the nail on the head with the identity. It explains a lot of seemingly random problems i've had the last week during testing. Thanks for the help!